# Mi sentencia SQL arroja un resultado equivocado

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una sentencia SQL en donde estoy intentando extraer las 4 publicaciones con mayor cantidad de visitas que existan dentro de la base de datos.

Para lograr eso estoy utilizando esta sentencia SQL:

```
SELECT
  post.id_post, post.title, post.miniatura,
  post.category, post.create_at_post
FROM post
INNER JOIN view
ORDER BY 'view' DESC LIMIT 4
```

### ¿Qué resultado estoy recibiendo?

Debo aclarar que no me lanza ningún tipo de error la sentencia, simplemente es que el resultado no es el correcto ya que me esta lanzado las 4 primeras publicaciones que publiqué y no las 4 con más visitas como debería de mostrar.

### ¿Como están estructuradas las tablas publicación y visitas?

```
CREATE TABLE post(
id_post             int(250) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_post_user        int(250) NOT NULL,
title               varchar(200) NOT NULL,
description_post    varchar(250) NOT NULL,
category            varchar(50) NOT NULL,
miniatura           varchar(250) NOT NULL,
img_description     varchar(250),
entrada             text NOT NULL,
tags                varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`status`            varchar(50),
browser_post        varchar(200),
ip_post             varchar(200),
create_at_post      datetime,
CONSTRAINT fk_post_user FOREIGN KEY(id_post_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE `view`(
id_view             int(250) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_view_post        int(250) NOT NULL,
view                int(250),
browser_view        varchar(200),
ip_view             varchar(200),
create_at_view      datetime,
CONSTRAINT fk_view_post FOREIGN KEY(id_view_post) REFERENCES post(id_post)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Si necesitan saber alguna otra información para solucionar este problema no duden en dejarme saber.

NOTA: sé que llamar `view` a mi tabla fue un error ya que `view` es una palabra reservada de SQL y eso me podría traer problemas en un futuro.

Pero lo cierto es que no tomé esto en cuenta cuando estuve maquetando la base de datos y hacer ese cambio ahora no es para nada fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes viene del nombre de la tabla "view", por no tener un JOIN sobre columnas específicas y también por no usar un nombre de columna específico en el orden de la tabla.

Intenta con esto:

```
SELECT
post.id_post,
post.title, 
post.miniatura,
post.category,
post.create_at_post
FROM post INNER JOIN `view` on post.id_post = `view`.id_view_post
ORDER BY `view`.view DESC LIMIT 4
```

Al declarar el join sobre columnas específicas con **"on post.id_post = `view`.id_view_post"** y encerrar el nombre de tabla entre comillas invertidas ya se puede interpretar la consulta.

Y como ya te has dado cuenta, no es buena idea nombrar tablas con identificadores reservados.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como tienes la consulta SQL tendrás repetido el número máximo de visualizaciones tantas veces como registros tengas en la tabla de publicaciones debido a cómo funciona un `JOIN` sin ninguna restricción: combina cada registro de la tabla A con el de la tabla B (A x B).

Lo que necesitas es relacionar qué campos de la tabla A corresponden con los de la tabla B con un `JOIN ... ON ...`:

```
SELECT
  post.id_post,
  post.title,
  view
FROM post
INNER JOIN view
  ON view.id_view_post = post.id_post
ORDER BY view DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Ver en línea:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/373QLHbfdCzWYwdVDhgpjb/0

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas obtener la salida esperada antes debes considerar:

1. Al momento solo estás haciendo un ordenamiento de los resultados, pero no aplicas alguna operación matemática que ayude a identificar el post con mayor cantidad de visitas
2. La columna que en este caso te ayudará a identificar el número de veces que un post esta siendo visto es la llave foránea `id_view_post` pues es el vínculo con cada post leido

   ```
   SELECT post.title, COUNT(`view.id_view_post`) AS TotalVisitas
   FROM post
   INNER JOIN `view` ON post.id_post = `view.id_view_post`
   GROUP BY post.title
   ORDER BY TotalVisitas DESC
   LIMIT 4;
   ```

Comment: Si existe más de un registro en `view` por cada publicación en `post` quizá sea mejor agrupar por `post.id_post` que por el título. Los títulos podrían repetirse, una clave primaria no.

Comment: Parece que la tabla view tiene una columna "view" que lleva esos conteos

Comment: @EduardoHernández lo sé, pero al menos desde mi pobre perspectiva ese valor no se me hace del todo necesario si puedo evaluar cuantas veces aparece un post como leido con base en la aparición de su id en la tablas views, igual solo es una forma de ver el contexto del problema (*ya que estoy visualizando el problema de determinada manera*), por otro lado Oscar tienes mucha razón, es una posibilidad, gracias por hacerlo notar

Comment: @BetaM. Concuerdo totalmente. Yo tomaría exactamente la misma ruta al diseñar la base de datos. Mi comentario trata de poner la atención en el contexto de la pregunta una vez que ya diseñó de esa forma la base de datos. De nuevo, yo lo haría igual que lo que propones, solamente que quien hizo la pregunta se fue por otro lado :)